# Is it possible to get the exact pixel size of (css) zoomed text?

Tags: html, css, zooming

I have some text that is set to 17 pixels.
I then have some css setting the zoom of this text to zoom: 1.1

```
<div class="text">This is some text</div>
.text {
  font-size: 17px;
  zoom: 1.1;
}
```

Is it possible to work out exactly how big the font is in the browser? (In the 'computed' section it is still telling me it is 17px)

Or is there a calculation that will allow me to work it out?
Will the font size simply be 17 * 1.1 = 18.7px?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate zoom * font-size. Careful, `zoom` CSS property is deprecated : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: Yes, I am trying to remove it, but there are many entries and I need some easy way to know the conversion from the zoomed size to the pixel size. Thanks very much.

Comment: Would this help you ? `font-size: calc(17px * 1.1);` ?